# redirection is happening in ionic serve but not on device

Tags: ionic-framework, angular6, ionic4, inappbrowser

I am launching external url on a button click by using window.location.replace

```
Login(){
    window.location.replace("https://localdomain.com");
}
```

In ionic serve, after the click it redirects to "https://localdomain.com/uaa/login" and letting me to Login with corresponding cookies & header info coming as expected.

But if the same is tried in mobile i.e. after the apk build and opened in the device.
After the click, It shows below instead of redirecting to /uaa/login. so if understand correctly, redirection is not handled by default in ionic's webview? if so how to handle it?

[image]

I see the below console log from device inspect when above error comes.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 () /favicon.ico:1
```

Comment: you need to check the console. Connect your device and go to chrome://inspect

Comment: added console logs.

Comment: Use: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser

Comment: You have to use InAppBrowser plugin to open any external URL from the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem with inappbrowser. The back end server of the URL I'm loading in inappbrowser is having error in the logs. Resolved after fixing them